# Loading images with java is taking me too many resources.. which would be the way around it to make my program look pritty?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, resources, paintcomponent

So I'm supposed to kinda recreate the game "ruzzle" for a school project in java. The thing is that I wanted to make custom buttons for the letters instead of the same old and boring JButton, so I tried putting images inside the button with the paintComponent (with image buffer).. It didn't work out quite the way I was expecting to.. it did show up the images but the amount of resources the screen took was ridiculous (like 40 MB of ram for an image of around 100K). So I was wondering how do you make a program look "pretty"? Like windows for instance even has sancy animations when copying files for example, how do them animation not take an insane amount of resources?

Which would the solution be? I've been thinking about this.. now, the image was a .png file, would it make a difference if I put a vectorial image? Should I resize it for the right appearance and cut off the excesses? Or should I just get better with the paint method? (Which is the thing I'd try to avoid.. it'd be soooo annoying to do!!!)

Answer (score 1):

> I tried putting images inside the button with the paintComponent (with image buffer)..

Not sure why you are doing custom painting. You can just add an `ImageIcon` to the button.

I did a quick test with a JFrame and a single JLabel and got the following memory requirement according to Windows Task Manageer:

1. 18,068K with 10 character of text
2. 20,060K with image size of 24K
3. 27,000k with image size of 132K
4. 82,000k with image size of 397K

So yes, memory usage does go up with image size, but I also question why you need an image of 100k for the button. Usually Icons on a button are small. For example the gif files used in the [How to Use a Tool Bars](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/toolbar.html) tutorial are all less than 500 bytes.

Answer (score 0):

Use vector graphics instead of images.